# vim: code to ps; ex mode, silent mode, hardcopy, syntax on

Tags: bash, vim, printing, syntax-highlighting

I've been trying to add a function to my .bash_profile script to easily convert/print (most) code files to .ps files. 
My first try...

```
    #TRY1
    code2ps() {
        if [ -z $1 ]; then
            echo "ERROR: argument missing\n code2ps [targetfile]"
        else
            ex -c "open $1" -c "syntax on" -c "hardcopy > $1.ps" -c q
        fi
    }
```

...works. However, there is still a short flickering since vim is opened and closed in the terminal window.

My second try...

```
    #TRY2
    code2ps() {
        if [ -z $1 ]; then
            echo "ERROR: argument missing\n code2ps [targetfile]"
        else
            ex -s -c "open $1" -c "syntax on" -c "hardcopy > $1.ps" -c q
        fi
    }
```

...avoids the flickering by using the silent mode -s, but produces a .ps file without any syntax being highlighted.

What am I missing?

---

And additionally:

That one does not work at all, why?

```
    #TRY3
    code2ps() {
        if [ -z $1 ]; then
            echo "ERROR: argument missing\n code2ps [targetfile]"
        else
            string=$(printf 'ex -c \"open %s\" -c \"syntax on\" -c \"hardcopy > %s.ps\" -c q' $1 $1)
            $string
            echo "Executed: $string"
        fi
    }
```

Thx in advance!

----------EDIT----------

One more thing: I added a few lines to convert on to pdf:

```
    code2pdf() {
        in_file="${1}"      #input filename
        ps_file="${1}.ps"   #filename.ps
        pdf_file="${1}.pdf" #filename.pdf

        if [[ $in_file == "" ]]
        then
            echo "ERROR: argument missing: code2pdf [targetfile]"
        else
            code2ps $in_file #convert code to .ps
            ps2pdf $ps_file $pdf_file #convert .ps to .pdf
            rm $ps_file #remove .ps fi
    }
```

which works fine. But is there a simpler way, maybe by piping the output from code2ps() ?

```
code2ps xxx | ps2pdf
```

doesn't work...

Comment: What about `ex ... >& /dev/null`?

Comment: could you may explain? what is /dev/null?

Comment: That will redirect all output to `/dev/null` (black hole) so there's no *flickering*.

Comment: answering the edit in a new answer; it's a rather different question and requires some more explanation than fits in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things; `if [ -z $1 ];` At least, quote `"$1"`; Not sure about current versions, but I think test will whine about not having a parameter if `$1` is not set, which you are testing on. A more readable option would be if `[[ "${1}" == "" ]];` works most of the times.

Try2 seems to mess up ex's knowledge of colors available; it *does* syntax highlighting, but without colors... not exactly what you had in mind.

Try3 might fail because the `$(printf ... )` should be quoted. `string="$(printf ...)"`

The actual answer was provided by Emily E: by redirecting (the mostly absent) output (flicker) to `/dev/null` (the bit bucket, generally used for all output that is to be discarded [it contains the last bit redirected to it]) you can get rid of that flicker.

So the correct script would be:

```
 code2ps() {
    if [[ "${1}" == "" ]]
    then
        echo "ERROR: argument missing\n code2ps [targetfile]"
    else
        ex -c "open ${1}" -c "syntax on" -c "hardcopy > ${1}.ps" -c q >/dev/null
    fi
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I edited my question/added a small extra part, could you may help? I'm new to bash&stack-overflow, hope that is alright.

Answer (score 0):

The second question (after the edit) needs some explanation.
Since, to prevent flickering, the output of `ex` is redirected to `/dev/null` a normal pipe won't work.

The hardcopy command would have to write to stdout, but that output gets redirected to `/dev/null`; You might get around that by creating some extra filedescriptors and some redirecting, but frankly; I think that would not make your code more readable or more efficient. Unless you're hard pressed for diskspace, I'd go for your solution of making the intermediary postscript file.

Another solution would be to create a virtual printer that generates pdf files and let ex send the hardcopy to that one. That does save the extra step and keeps matters pretty clean.